# Java: Cannot find symbol: variable Objects

Tags: java, object, equals, javac, hashcode

I generated methods hashCode() and equals(Object obj) by netbeans insercode. In netbeans I can compile without errors, but when I compile it on my server with javac:

```
bangserver/Login.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Objects
location: package java.util
import java.util.Objects;
                ^
```

and other errors with Objects...

```
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.password);
    return hash;
}
```

What you guys think should be problem he can't find java.util.Objects ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're compiling with a Java verson older than Java 7, since `java.util.Objects` was only added in Java 7.

Comment: java -version ->"1.6.0_26"
It would be problem Thanks.

Comment: This isn't always the case.  I got the same error using Java 8 and only when I fully qualified Objects did it work - Change to java.util.Objects.toString("","") and it compiles.